# Notepad++: Automatic "comment line (*)" on newline

Tags: notepad++, eclipse, autocomplete, comments

is there a way to make notepad++ behave like eclipse with multi-line comments?
It would be great if notepad automatically inserts " * " every time I make a new line in a /* */ comment-section.

To be clearify my question:

When if have this code:

```
/**
 * Some descriptive comment [cursor]
```

And I press [Enter] it would be nice to see notepad automatically do the following:

```
/**
 * Some descriptive comment
 * [cursor]
```

I hope this is understandable.

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: Only Javascript and PHP.

Comment: Hmm. It already does **exactly** what you want for `.js.` and `.php` files.

Comment: Actually not in my notepad. Which option enables/disables it? Maybe I disabled it by accident.

Comment: No idea. Do you have the correct lange set for your file? "Language" > "Javascript" or "PHP"?

Comment: Yes the language is correct.

Comment: Then I would uninstall/reinstall Notepad++ - probably the fastest way to restore any defaults settings you may have changed.

Comment: Ok, I will try that. But I this will take some time (Until evening, to be a bit more precise)

Comment: It that doesn't work then I've really no idea what is going on. I created new .js and .php files, typed `/**`, pressed enter, and the next line was <space>`*`<space> with the `*` under the first `*` in the line above ...

Comment: OK. I see the problem - if the second line contains text then the `*` in the third line has no leading space. Is this what you are trying to fix (the missing space)? I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: @DavidPostill Ok, that is exact the behavior I want. Strangely this is not working for me. I try to reinstall it this evening, and let you know, if that solves it.

Comment: Many years later, I have the same problem when writing shell scripts. I start a line with `#`, type the comment, and then type [Enter]. I expect the new line to automatically start with `#` but it is just a blank line. Is this a setting I can change, like "Continue comment when inserting new line" in RStudio?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familliar with the ability to do so automatically on Notepad++, so you may try starting with writing your multi line comment, then select it and use the  shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to encapsulate it in a comment block.

Comment: No need to do this. What the OP wants is built-in and works exactly how he would like it to.

Comment: Not quite what I was expecting, as the formation is not what I am supposed to use. But thanks for the quick answer.